# Modifying the array of an instanced buffer attribute in three js

Tags: javascript, kotlin, three.js

I'm having trouble modifying the contents of an InstancedBufferAttribute array in three.js - I can set it up fine and the mesh renders as expected, but running the following code to modify the contents of the attribute

```
        heights.set(x + y * params.patchWidth, height.toFloat())
        heightAttribute.needsUpdate = true
```

does nothing (note that this is kotlin compiling to JS, to explain the toFloat() and other idiosyncracies). While debugging I can see that after setting needsUpdate, it immediately becomes undefined and the version is incremented. I've also tried changing the array assigned to the attribute to a new one containing the modified values with no luck. Finally, setting the attribute to dynamic doesn't help either.

Comment: "after setting needsUpdate, it immediately becomes undefined and the version is incremented." - that is exactly how it should work: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/src/core/BufferAttribute.js#L32-L40

Comment: From your code we can't see the connection between `heights` and `heightsAttribute`. Can you try to use `heightsAttribute.array` directly?

Comment: @Martin yes I figured that was how it should work regarding needsUpdate. I'll try modifying heightsAttribute.array directly (heights is the initial Float32Array that is passed to the attribute constructor)

Comment: Just to confirm directly modifying heightsAttribute.array does not work

Comment: @Andy Could you provide a live code example? Or more code, that the others could understand what and how you try to do.

Comment: Many thanks for checking guys - I did indeed make an example (http://jsfiddle.net/kc4egp9b/3/) but in doing so I found out that I was reusing the attributes in multiple geometries and this was what wasn't working. I'll close out the question